# JSF rendered form not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, rendering

I have this problem with JSF rendering. I have this bean containing boolean type value `ulogovan`.

```
    @Named("sessionBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class SessionBean implements Serializable{
    private boolean ulogovan;
    private Zaposleni ulogovanZaposleni;

    public SessionBean() {
        ulogovan = false;
        ulogovanZaposleni = null;
    }    
    public boolean getUlogovan() {
        return ulogovan;
    }    
    public void setUlogovan(boolean ulogovan) {
        this.ulogovan = ulogovan;
    }
```

I have to show a form depending on a value of `ulogovan`. Here is the begining of the form:

```
<h:form id="form" rendered="#{sessionBean.ulogovan == true}">
```

Comment: what do you want to do? and what is the error you got ?

Comment: i dont get any error it just doesnt show form in any way

Comment: In addition to the answer, avoid the usage of a constructor in the bean for this case. Use `@PostConstruct` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ulogovan = false;` so when you said `#{sessionBean.ulogovan == true}` that mean `false == true` which is `false`. Thus, your form will not be rendered unless you set `ulogovan` to be `true`.

If you want your form to be rendered depending on the value of `ulogovan`, just do it like this:

```
<h:form id="form" rendered="#{sessionBean.ulogovan}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include @PostConstruct annotation on init() method.
So before rendering the page this method will be called first. 
You can set the condition in this you wish

```
@Named("sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable{
private boolean ulogovan;
private Zaposleni ulogovanZaposleni;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
      setUlogovan(false);
      ulogovanZaposleni = null;
} 

public boolean getUlogovan() {
    return ulogovan;
}    
public void setUlogovan(boolean ulogovan) {
    this.ulogovan = ulogovan;
}
```

This will work definately.